# Cannot access object model of PowerPoint opened from SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, vsto, ms-office, powerpoint, office-2010

I have a PowerPoint add-in that works with PowerPoint 2007/2010. I've discovered that it does **not** work correctly when the active presentation was opened from a SharePoint site in read-only mode.

In this scenario, various calls to the PowerPoint object model give the error

> Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)':
>
> Shape (unknown member) : Invalid request.  Presentation cannot be
>   modified.

This includes apparently benign things like `Presentation.SaveAs`, `Presentation.SaveCopyAs`, accessing `Shape.Tags`, etc. All give the same error.

While my add-in is coded in C#/VSTO, I've verified that in fact these same things cause the same error even when just entered executed directly in the VBA immediate window.

This is something of a disaster for me, since it effectively means that my add-in cannot be used with documents opened from SharePoint - which accounts for the majority of them in some organisations.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: Is the read-only mode something imposed by SharePoint, or are do the presentation have a modify-password applied?

Comment: It's SharePoint. You have the option, when opening from SharePoint, whether to open read-only or not. Unfortunately, read-only is the default.

Comment: I think perhaps a better term is "server read-only", since that's what appears in the yellow bar at the top of the window. This is distinct from the "other" read-only mode where "[Read-only]" is appended to the window's title bar.

Comment: Thanks for adding that distinction. It makes sense that certain things wouldn't be allowed, but sheesh ... examining tag values is verboten?

Comment: Yeah. And SaveCopyAs is not allowed either (or any way to get your hands on the doc). Given that SaveCopyAs doesn't change the original, "read only" is a misnomer IMO.

Comment: If this particular brand of R/O is implemented through Information Rights Management, there'd be the ability to enforce this kind of limitation ... that is, to make the file REALLY read-only, so that any recipient can read but not alter/save/copy/print it at all.  Sounds as though that might be what's going on.

Comment: Hmmm, I don't think it's related to that - it's a SharePoint integration "feature". And yes, it *is* really read-only - to the extent that all the menus (or rather ribbons) are grayed out, and you can't enter any text or manipulate shapes with the mouse.

Comment: PS. I should have made it clearer that most parts of the object model do work. Some do, some don't, and it's not at all obvious which ones will work, since some of the apparently-benign ones fail. Oh, and it's a different set of methods on PowerPoint 2007 v. 2010!

Comment: I've tossed this out to a Sharepoint-aware friend of mine who suggests that it might be an IRM/view-only setting at the SP end.  If you're permitted only to view the file, things like checking tags (or even doc properties) might indeed be locked out. If we sort out anything definite, I'll give a shout.